# AWS Forgot password: Unable to verify secret hash for client for iOS

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-mobilehub

**Solution for iOS**

When submitting a forgotten password request to the aws cognito identity pool, the request must be signed with the client's secret in combination with the username being submitted in the forgot password request.

How can we create the "secretHash" from the client secret and the username within swift in the format required by aws?

Answer (score 3):

This functionality is not documented and is only found in the tests of some AWS libraries. This code serves as an example of submitting a forgot password request until the functionality is better supported within the AWSCongitoIdentityUserPool library.

**Swift 3.2**

```
func forgotPassword(username: String) {
   let pool = AWSCognitoIdentityUserPool.default()

   let request = AWSCognitoIdentityProviderForgotPasswordRequest()
   request?.username = username
   request?.clientId = pool.userPoolConfiguration.clientId
   request?.secretHash = pool.calculateSecretHash(username: username)

   AWSCognitoIdentityProvider.default().forgotPassword(request!) { (response, error) in
       if let error = error {
           print(error)
       }
       else {
           print("success")
       }
    }
}
```

Signing the username with the client secret from the user pool.

```
extension AWSCognitoIdentityUserPool {
    func calculateSecretHash(username: String) -> String? {
        guard let clientSecret = userPoolConfiguration.clientSecret else {
            return nil
        }
        guard let key = clientSecret.data(using: String.Encoding.ascii) else {
            return nil
        }
        guard let data = (username + userPoolConfiguration.clientId).data(using: String.Encoding.utf8) else {
            return nil
        }

        let hmac = sign256(data: data, key: key)
        return hmac.base64EncodedString()
    }

    fileprivate func sign256(data: Data, key: Data) -> Data {
        let algorithm: CCHmacAlgorithm = CCHmacAlgorithm(kCCHmacAlgSHA256)
        let digestLength =  Int(CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH)
        let signature = UnsafeMutablePointer<CUnsignedChar>.allocate(capacity: digestLength)
        defer { signature.deallocate(capacity: digestLength) }

        data.withUnsafeBytes { dataBytes in
            key.withUnsafeBytes { keyBytes in
                CCHmac(algorithm, keyBytes, key.count, dataBytes, data.count, signature)
            }
        }

        return Data(bytes: signature, count: digestLength)
    }

}
```

Comment: This seems to be the correct answer still in Nov 2018. Thank you for your work